# How to add custom CSS files globally for angular 6 project

Tags: css, angular, angular6

In angular.json file, if I add

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "src/utility/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css",
  "src/utility/vendor/font-awesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css",
  "src/utility/vendor/animate.css/animate.min.css",
  "src/utility/vendor/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css",
  "src/utility/css/front.css",
  "src/utility/css/codepen.css"
],
```

these files are accessible only for index.html file, and not app.component.html or  any component as well. Other components are not even being rendered with the same content of index.html, but index.html is working fine.

Comment: anything u declare in styles.css under src folder is global

Comment: Your style.css should be at the very end of the list.

Comment: i know but i want other files to b separately global

Comment: Please extend your answer regarding the styles that are actually included in the rendered html page when you inspect it with dev tools.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1: Configure angular.json:

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "styles.scss"
]
```

2: Import directly in src/style.css or src/style.scss:

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

**Alternative: Local Bootstrap CSS**
If you added the Bootstrap CSS file locally, just import it in angular.json

```
"styles": [
  "styles/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "styles.scss"
],
```

or src/style.css:

```
@import './styles/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

I personally prefer to import all my styles in src/style.css since it’s been declared in angular.json already.

Answer (score 2):

Any CSS style file added to styles array at angular.json will be injected to `index.html` and will be a globally this mean **any** class added in these files you can use it inside any component.

another way is to add style file manually to index.html this work if the file host on **cdn** or in the **assets** folder.